# Each array every time i want

Tags: php

How can i have in each array every time i want definitely random and how much it will be

```
function randomDigits($numDigits) {
    if ($numDigits <= 0) {
        return '';
    }
    return mt_rand(0, 50) . randomDigits($numDigits - 1);
}
function randomDigitsLame($numDigits) {
    $digits = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numDigits; ++$i) {
        $digits .= mt_rand(0, 1000);
    }
    return $digits;
}
$maxq = 100;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxq; $i++) {
    echo $i . "<br>\n";
    echo randomDigits($i) . "<br>\n----<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you've got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe recursion is not suiting your requirement so i tweak in code.

This code gives you each time `1000` numbers. Means it will give you 100 times `1000` numbers. I have removed `randomDigitsLame` function because you were not using it.

```
function randomDigits($numDigits) {
    $arrayRange = 1000;
    if ($numDigits <= 0) {
        return '';
    } else{
        for($i=0; $i<$arrayRange; $i++){
            echo mt_rand(0, 50) ." ";
        }
    }

}
$maxq = 100;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxq; $i++) {
    //echo $i . "<br>\n"; ==>>> commented
    randomDigits($i) . "<br>\n----<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Oooops that's not number of array it was an extra `echo` which i have removed. You can see commented line in snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to do that for you.

```
function makeArray($size,$rand1,$rand2) {

$array = array();

while ($size > 0) {
array_push($array, mt_rand($rand1,$rand2));
$size--;
}

return $array;

}

print_r(makeArray(1000,0,50));
```

Comment: this code is good, but i need 100 arrays with 1000 numbers from 0 to 50 (random). It's generate just 1 array with 1000 numbers, and i need 100 arrays. Thnks